# undefined last inserted id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to get last inserted id

```
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
   $row = $stmt->fetch();
   echo $row['id'];
```

**js**

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
}
```

Result: `undefined` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must assign the proper alias

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id;");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo $row['id'];
```

otherwise echo $row['id'] is empty

Answer (score 2):

LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the last id from a previous insert statement. If you want the most recently inserted record and are using Auto Increment Prime keys, you can use the code below:

`SELECT MAX( id ) FROM table tablename;`
If you need to know what the NEXT id will be, you can get this from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

`SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'`